# Вывод блок кода два раза, не могу понять чего

Tags: java

У меня есть код, типа справочника, на самом деле фигня для практики, не важно. И почему-то выводится дважды текст, не могу понять.

Фото вывода: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmhKP.jpg)

```java
import java.io.IOException;

class Help{
    static void dovidka() throws IOException {
        char x;
        do {
            System.out.println("Введите цифру, которая соответствует нужной информации");
            System.out.println("Введите \"q\" для выхода из программы.");
            System.out.println("1. if");
            System.out.println("2. while");
            System.out.println("3. for");
            x = (char) System.in.read();
            switch (x) {
                case 'q':
                    System.out.println("Выходим из программы");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про if" + "\n");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про while" + "\n");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про for" + "\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while (x != 'q');
    }
}

public class example{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Help.dovidka();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы использовали `x = (char) System.in.read();`, метод read() считывает данные побайтно(один байт за раз). Теперь вы запускаете свою программу, вводите например `1` и нажимаете `enter`, и этот `enter` отображается в
`\n`, получается вы ввели и `1` и `\n`.

Разберем цикл:

- Ввели 1
- считали 1 `x = (char) System.in.read();`
- попал по switch case в свой блок кода
- вывел `System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про if" + "\n");`
- падаем до низа в пост условие `while (x != 'q')`, получается `('1'!= 'q')` это true
- цикл повторяется
- цикл повторяется, выводится информация

  ```
           System.out.println("Введите цифру, которая соответствует нужной информации");
           System.out.println("Введите \"q\" для выхода из программы.");
           System.out.println("1. if");
           System.out.println("2. while");
           System.out.println("3. for");
  ```
- так как вы ввели `1` и `enter`, то после единицы идет `\n`, поэтому метод
  read() считывает `\n` и пропускает процесс ввода информации с консоли, потому что у него есть что читать, еще с прошлого раза и это символ `\n`
- далее смотрим по `switch case`, а у нас нету `case`, удовлетворяющий
  `\n`
  потом мы падаем до низа в пост условие `while (x != 'q')`, получается (`'\n'!= 'q'`) это true
- цикл повторяется, поэтому у вас опять выводится информация

  ```
           System.out.println("Введите цифру, которая соответствует нужной информации");
           System.out.println("Введите \"q\" для выхода из программы.");
           System.out.println("1. if");
           System.out.println("2. while");
           System.out.println("3. for");
  ```

Можно использовать **Scanner**:

- при считывании данных, он делит их на части, по какому-то патерну (по умолчанию  `Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{javaWhitespace}+")`, можете сами задать патерн) с
  помощью регулярного выражения и считывает int:

  ```
   static void dovidka() throws IOException {
           char x;
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           do {
               System.out.println("Введите цифру, которая соответствует нужной информации");
               System.out.println("Введите \"q\" для выхода из программы.");
               System.out.println("1. if");
               System.out.println("2. while");
               System.out.println("3. for");
               x = (char) scanner.nextInt();
               switch (x) {
                   case 'q':
                       System.out.println("Выходим из программы");
                       break;
                   case '1':
                       System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про if" + "\n");
                       break;
                   case '2':
                       System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про while" + "\n");
                       break;
                   case '3':
                       System.out.println("Возможно, будет инфа про for" + "\n");
                       break;
               }
           } while (x != 'q');
       }
  ```

Дополнительно:

- Про System.in:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read
- Про Scanner:
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Спасибо! Если не сложно, скажите, пожалуйста, почему повлияло на вывод то, как я запрашиваю информацию у пользователя?

Comment: Дополнил ответ,  думаю стало понятней, надеюсь что мой ответ вам помог.